# How to debug launching of Karma runner vs PhantomJS browser?

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have problem with running unit tests with Karma runner + PhantomJS browser.

Karma server starts, then PhantomJS browsers starts and then nothing happens. After 1 minute I am getting message about nothing was capured in 60s, killing process.

```
[11:08:35][Step 3/5] Running "karma:allTests" (karma) task
[11:08:36][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:08:36.520:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/export/home/bc_prod1/buildAgent1/work/dac7c6b3e0abf1a1/test/fixtures/*.json" does not match any file.
[11:08:41][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:08:41.077:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.21 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[11:08:41][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:08:41.084:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
[11:09:41][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:09:41.085:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[11:09:43][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:09:43.087:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
[11:09:45][Step 3/5] 26 03 2016 11:09:45.087:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
[11:09:45][Step 3/5] Warning: Task "karma:allTests" failed.  Use --force to continue.
```

I don't know why it is not starting. How I can debug this problem? I have no idea.

OS is redhat6.

Answer (score 1):

There are some incompatibility issues with different versions of karma-phantomjs-launcher and phantomjs-prebuilt.

Try downgrading your version of phantomjs-prebuilt.